# Read binary numbers from file and separate integers from longs/doubles

Tags: java, integer, double, binaryfiles, mixed

In this programmer i found Prime numbers in first 100.Numbers are in INT format and totally number of them is in DOUBLE format.I want to read that file and i did it for only INT numbers but i dont know hot to do it for DOUBLE number.
Here is the code:

```
package int1;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.DoubleBuffer;
import java.nio.IntBuffer;
import java.nio.LongBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;

public class int_upis {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    File a = new File("C:\\Users\\Jovan\\Desktop\\Pisem.txt");
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(a);
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
    FileChannel ch = fos.getChannel();
    ByteBuffer bff = ByteBuffer.allocate(100);
    IntBuffer ibf = bff.asIntBuffer(); // Int type
    DoubleBuffer db = bff.asDoubleBuffer(); // Double type
    double p = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
        int t = 0;
        for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
            if (i % j == 0) {
                t = t + 1;
            }

        }
        if (t < 3) {
            p = p + 1; // number of Prime numbers
            System.out.println(i);
            ibf.put(i);
            bff.position(4 * ibf.position());
            bff.flip();
            try {
                ch.write(bff);
                bff.clear();
                ibf.clear();
            } catch (IOException e) {

            }
        }

    }

    try {
        db.put(p); //At the end of the txt-file i put double format of number (Number of Prime numbers)
        bff.position(8*db.position());
        bff.flip();
        ch.write(bff);

        System.out.println("File is writen with: " + ch.size());
        ch.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

}
```

Now I tried to read this file:

```
public class int_ispis {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    File a = new File("C:\\Users\\Jovan\\Desktop\\Pisem.txt");
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    try {
        fis = new FileInputStream(a);
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
    FileChannel ch = fis.getChannel();
    ByteBuffer bff = ByteBuffer.allocate(6 * 4);
```

This is one line of Prime Number put in a 6-row array (this line below):

```
    int[] niz = new int[6];
    System.out.println("Pre flipa: " + bff.position() + " " + bff.limit());
    System.out.println("++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");
    while (ch.read(bff) != -1) {

        bff.flip();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Posle flipa: " + bff.position() + " " + bff.limit());
        IntBuffer ib = bff.asIntBuffer();
        System.out.println("IB: " + ib.position() + " " + ib.limit());

        int read = ib.remaining();
        System.out.println(read);
```

When it come to the end of file it puts Double Number as Integer and writes wrong  number(How to separate Integer form Double number?)

```
        ib.get(niz, 0, ib.remaining());
        for (int i = 0; i < read; i++) {
            System.out.print(niz[i] + " ");

        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("=================================");
        ib.clear();
        bff.clear();

    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A binary file does not have any "separators".

You need to know the *structure* of the file content and use this knowledge.

> In this programmer i found Prime numbers in first 100.Numbers are in INT format and totally number of them is in DOUBLE format.

This means that there is only one `long` value in the file and this is in  the *last 8 bytes*. So you simply have to check if the current position is `fileLenght - 8` and then read these last 8 bytes as a `long` value.

Comment: That's true only for this specific file format, but the question title asks more generally

Comment: @smci My first two lines state: "there is no general answer". Feel free to post your own answer if you know better.

Comment: You misunderstood me; I wasn't talking about separators; and yes there is a general answer. I meant you rely on the file format being all integer with only one long at the end, you don't detect overflow on those integers. It's trivially easy to detect overflow from the string length of the number (the highest one bit).

Comment: @smci *"you rely on the file format being all integer with only one long at the end"* I don't. It was the OPs statement. ---- *"It's trivially easy to detect overflow from the string length of the number (the highest one bit)"* no it is not. You don't know at which position a certain byte belongs in a number unless you know the structure of the files content. **there are no implicit separators between numbers in a binary file.**

Comment: ah my mistake, I read "binary numbers from file", thought OP meant whitespace-separated. Yes you're right, if it was a binary file this would be painful.